# WatTmdb api get movie id

Tags: c#, api, movie

I have a program that gets the movie title from a search and I would now like to get the TMDB ID from the movie title. I am using **wattmdb**  My current code is:

```
MovieTitle = txtMovieTitle.Text;
List<MovieResult> queryMovie = new List<MovieResult>();
  try
    {
     queryMovie = API.SearchMovie(MovieTitle, 1).results;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException) { }
    listBox1.DataSource = queryMovie;
```

I am trying to extract the TMDB ID from the searched movie, I have looked on the documentation page and there is no title to id parser. So any help would be lovely.
The link is [here.](http://wattmdb.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 1):

The TMDB ID is included in the response to call to SearchMovie.  In your sample code the **title** and the **id** members are included in each MovieResult object in the queryMovie list.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I found the answer a while ago. Should probably update the question.